# Firebase Admin Node.js SDK Caching Approach

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm building an service (let's say it's a easy bulletin platform) with RESTful API, and I use Firebase (Cloud Firestore) as my DB.

I just use Firebase admin SDK only, which means every read/write are through my Node.js server. Since there's no offline caching/persistence for Firebase admin SDK, every time my "read request" counts.

example code:

```
app.get('/message/:cid', async (ctx) => {
    const msg = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc(ctx.params.cid).get();
    await ctx.render('message', { ...msg.data() });
});
```

I'm thinking if I can do some LRU cache to save my recent bulletin messages so that the it saves not only Firebase usage but also some time. Is it a good approach? For performance and usage. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a LRU cache to increase performance (and in this case also reduce cost) sounds like a reasonable approach.

Definitely also spend some time thinking about cache invalidation though. If something changes in `/messages`, how will you know, and how will you prevent serving stale content from the cache?

A typical way might be to use more persistent listeners, which keep an open connection to Firestore. For example, [start listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) when you add something to the cache, and remove the listener when the item gets expunged from that case. If the listener fires an update, you can update the item in the cache . This will still allow you to reduce reads, but at the same time ensure that you never serve stale content.

Comment: I didn't consider using listeners because I build my own API, which means every request to edit, remove message will go through my server, and I can delete the cache at that time.

Comment: Any time => cool. Just consider how you'll expire outdated content, because using a time-to-live is pretty suboptimal, while realtime listeners make it much easier to maintain an always-up-to-date cache.